# Appearance of the button pressed when performing

Tags: java, android, button

Let me start by saying that I am using the standard buttons.
When you push the button, my program performs a method, and until it does, the looks on down. I would like to change the text in the button when this method is performed, after I would like to have a text as the beginning.
Do I need to encode something? Whether enough suitable property in xml?

Answer (score 1):

This is easily achieved.

First initiate

```
private Button btn1;
```

then assign

```
btn1 = (Button) findviewById(R.id.//id_name_of_your_button);
```

now add an Onclicklisenere

```
btn1.setOnclickListener(new OnClick....
```

when clicking on your button change text or add any other value around

```
btn1.setText("patrick1980 kick ass!");
```

Enjoy